# Firebase with custom domain using JustHost.com

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I'm trying to set up my firebase app and use the custom domain I've purchased. I've followed the instructions and put the TXT file in the DNS settings on the JustHost website, but for some reason I still haven't been able to verify the domain in Firebase. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Here is the TXT set up in JustHost (I've blanked out the key to ask the question):
[image]

And here is the error i get in Firebase when I'm trying to verify:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On many DNS platforms you need to specify the <kbd>Host Record</kbd> value as `@`, instead of the name of the domain.

For example this is what I have for one of my domains at Gandi.net:

[image]